# Get rid of all ##### errors at once in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013

In Excel, I usually solve `#####` errors by double-clicking offending column headers. However, this can get a bit tedious when there are multiple error columns. Is there a quicker way to solve this?

Comment: No need to swear!

Comment: @AndrewGrimm, this is Excel we're talking about.

Comment: Is ##### actually an error?

Comment: @ScottSeidman it's not `#NULL!`, `DIV/0!`, `VALUE!`, `#REF!`, `#NAME?`, `#NUM!` or `#N/A` - so not, it wouldn't be identified as an error by something like `iferror()`

Comment: @Raystafarian -- then its just a display convention, or some such.

Answer (score 46):

You can autosize multiple columns at the same time by double clicking, just like you do with a single column.

### Step 1. Select multiple columns:

Either select all columns by clicking in the arrow in the upper-left corner:
[image]

Or click and drag to select a smaller range of columns:
[image]

### Step 2. Autosize selected columns:

Now double click on the right boundary of any of the selected columns, when your cursor changes to the column-resizing double arrow.

[image]

[image]

Comment: This is a worse solution than autofit because it resizes columns to the same width

Comment: @JamesRyan - It seems to autofit properly.  I just verified with different length values.  Are you sure you're double clicking to resize the column instead of clicking and dragging?

Comment: ah I think that has changed since earlier versions when I learnt not to do it

Answer (score 39):

Yes, on the ribbon go to *Home - Cells* and click *Format*

Under there, you can choose Autofit either Row Height or Column Width.

[image]

Comment: does this automatically do all columns in a worksheet?

Comment: This also resizes cells with text in them.

Answer (score 19):

For the keyboard warriors, here's a technique that doesn't require the mouse:

1. **Select all** - <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> or <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>8</kbd>
2. **AutoFit columns** - Hold <kbd>Alt</kbd>, then press in sequence <kbd>O</kbd>, <kbd>C</kbd>, <kbd>A</kbd>.  You can let go of <kbd>Alt</kbd> after you press <kbd>O</kbd>.

This feature, called [Office Access Keys](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Use-access-keys-from-Office-2003-in-Ribbon-programs-00017F69-0D9B-4A12-A6DA-3F01C61B1593) is a holdover from the pre-ribbon days.  If you had memorized the old menus, you can continue to access them this way.

In this case, the navigation was:

- F**o**rmat
- **C**olumn
- **A**utoFit

Comment: Alt H, O, I is the new access key for this... it seems a bit slower though as for me it takes a few seconds for office to draw the shortcut keys (which it doesn't bother with for the old keys).

Answer (score 2):

In addition to narrow columns, the hashes can also be displayed when a cell containing a large text is formatted as **Text**. In Excel 2003 (and before?), this [happens](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/923616) when the cell contains 256 to 1024 characters.

Changing the category from **Text** to **General** helps.